# Datacube ODC environment setup

Tags: open-data-cube

Problem with ODC environment

I am trying to setup datacube following this tutorial:
https://docs.dea.ga.gov.au/notebooks/DEA_datasets/DEA_Water_Observations.html#Loading-data

The first section of code appears to work OK:

```
from datacube.utils import masking
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '../Tools/')
from dea_tools.datahandling import wofs_fuser
from dea_tools.plotting import plot_wo
```

The next line throws an error:

`dc = datacube.Datacube(app='DEA_Water_Observations')`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> Cell In[43], line 1
> dc = datacube.Datacube(app='DEA_Water_Observations')
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datacube\api\core.py:87 in
> **init**
> index = index_connect(normalise_config(config),
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datacube\api\core.py:81 in
> normalise_config
> return LocalConfig.find(env=env)
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datacube\config.py:133 in find
> return LocalConfig(
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datacube\config.py:106 in
> **init**
> raise ValueError('No ODC environment, checked configurations for %s' % fallbacks)
>
> ValueError: No ODC environment, checked configurations for ['default',
> 'datacube']

This help page below suggests that there is a problem with the environment setup: "If you have trouble connecting make sure your environment is setup correctly, see Setting up your environment" -but 'Setting up your environment' is not explained - dead link. help please!

https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data-access-analysis/apis/datacube-class.html

- Spyder version: 5.1.5 None
- Python version: 3.9.12 64-bit
- Qt version: 5.9.7
- PyQt5 version: 5.9.2
- Operating System: Windows 10

Answer (score 4):

This notebook is designed to be run in the Digital Earth Australia Sandbox. The idea is that the Sandbox is a space where an ODC environment is already set up, and data is already present in the database.

You can review the documentation for signing up to the Sandbox here: https://docs.dea.ga.gov.au/setup/Sandbox/sandbox.html

If you want to analyse Digital Earth Australia data in a Python environment, without needing to install anything locally, the Sandbox is a great place to start. Installing the ODC on your local machine has more steps, and may be more complex than you need.